# Eureka service not reading its config file in Git repository using ConfigServer

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm trying trying to write some basic microservices examples. Firstly, I'm using a ConfigServer application using Spring, with this resources/application.yaml file:

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          default-label: main
          uri: https://github.com/mguzm4n/microservices-data
          search-paths: config-data
  application:
    name: config-server
```

You can see the repo: https://github.com/mguzm4n/microservices-data

For Eureka, in resources/bootstrap.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8081
```

I build first ConfigServer App and then Eureka service, so it can load its config on Git, but I can't manage it to work. Eureka ends up running on localhost:8080 instead of port 8761 as shown in https://github.com/mguzm4n/microservices-data/blob/main/config-data/eureka-server.yaml.

Could anyone help me?
I'm new using this concepts like a config server and eureka for registering other services, so I'm sorry if it's something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your eureka-server is not picking up the bootstrapping config.

First cause might be that this config file should be named `bootstrap.yml`, not `bootstrap.yaml`.

Also, since Spring Boot 2.4 bootstrapping via `bootstrap.yml` is disabled by default and the usual `application.yml` should be used instead or it can be enabled back by adding the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency to your project.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that about Spring Boot 2.4. Now Eureka server works fine.